# pthread reading from shared memory

Tags: c, cuda, pthreads

Coming from CUDA I'm interested in how shared memory is read from a thread and compares to the reading alignment requirements of CUDA. I'll used the following code as an example:

```
#include <sys/unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define THREADS 2

void * threadFun(void * args);

typedef struct {
    float * dataPtr;
    int tIdx,
    dSize;
} t_data;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int i,
    sizeData=5;
    void * status;

    float *data;

    t_data * d;

    pthread_t * threads;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    data=(float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * sizeData );
    threads=(pthread_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*THREADS);
    d = (t_data *) malloc (sizeof(t_data)*THREADS);

    data[0]=0.0;
    data[1]=0.1;
    data[2]=0.2;
    data[3]=0.3;
    data[4]=0.4;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    for (i=0; i<THREADS;i++)
    {
        d[i].tIdx=i;
        d[i].dataPtr=data;
        d[i].dSize=sizeData;
        pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,threadFun,(void *)(d+i));
    }

    for (i=0; i<THREADS; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i],&status);
        if(status);
            //Error;
    }
    return 0;
}

void * threadFun(void * args)
{
    int i;

    t_data * d= (t_data *) args;

    float sumVal=0.0;

    for (i=0; i<d->dSize; i++)
        sumVal+=d->dataPtr[i]*(d->tIdx+1);

    printf("Thread %d calculated the value as %-11.11f\n",d->tIdx,sumVal);

    return(NULL);
}
```

In the threadFun, the entire pointer d is pointing to shared memory space (I believe). From what I've encountered in documentation *reading* from multiple threads is ok. In CUDA reads need to be coalesced - is there similar alignment restrictions in pthreads? I.e. if I have two threads reading from the same shared address I'm assuming somewhere along the line a scheduler has to put one thread ahead of the other. In CUDA this could be a costly operation and should be avoided. Is there a penalty for 'simultaneous' reads from shared memory - and if so is it so small that it is negligible? i.e. both threads may need to read d->datPtr[0] simultaneously - I'm assuming that memory read cannot occur simultaneously - is this assumption wrong?

Also I read an [article from intel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/matrix-vector-multiplication-and-multi-threading-benefits/) that said to use a structure of arrays when multithreading - this is consistent with cuda. If I do this though, it is almost inevitable I will need the thread ID - which I believe will require me to  use a mutex lock the thread ID until it is read into the thread's scope, is this true or would there be some other way to identify threads?

An article on memory management for mulithreaded programs would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your thread data pointer `d` is pointing into a shared memory space, unless you increment that pointer to try and read from or write to an adjoining thread data element in the shared memory space array, you're basically dealing with localized thread data.  Also the value of `args` is local to each thread, so in both cases if you are not incrementing the data pointer itself (i.e., you're never calling something like `d++`, etc. so that you're pointing to another thread's memory), no mutex is needed to guard the memory "belonging" to your thread.

Also again for your thread ID, since you're only writing that value from the spawning thread, and then reading that value in the actual spawned thread, there is no need for a mutex or synchronization mechanism ... you only have a single producer/consumer for the data.  Mutexes and other synchronization mechanisms are only needed if there are multiple threads that will read and write the same data location.

Comment: but the data pointed to in d by dataPtr is a shared address. In my example both threads are reading from a shared memory address to compute the sum, and could potentially read simultaneously. I'm interestedin how this happens - can two threads read 'simultaneously' or is there some scheduler that will actually divide the two reads? If the two threads *can* read simultaneously, how does this work?

Comment: It depends.  First is that the sequence of reads will be non-deterministic, meaning unless you add a syncronization mechanism, you are not going to be able to deterministically tell which thread will read first.  That being said, the thread local pointer `d` is *not* pointing to shared memory.  The pointer `d->dataPtr` *is* pointing to shared memory.  On a single-processor system, the arbitration to `d->dataPtr` would be done through the software scheduler.  On a multiprocessor system though, the arbitration would be done at the hardware memory controller level.

Comment: The reason for this is because on a single-processor system, you're basically doing time-slicing of the processor execution time among threads, and the software scheduler handles what threads are run at any given time.  A multi-processor system though can actually execute two different threads at the same time, so if both processors are trying to read the exact same memory location, then that arbitration cannot be done at the software level, and happens at the hardware level, either through pre-fetching data into local caches, issuing cache-coherency calls, etc.

Answer (score 1):

CPUs have caches. Reads come from caches, so each CPU/core can read from its own cache, as long as the corresponding cacheline is SHARED. Writes force cachelines into EXCLUSIVE state, invalidating the corresponding cachelines on other CPUs.

If you have an array with a member per thread, and there are both reads and writes to that array, you may want to align every member to a cacheline, to avoid false sharing.

Answer (score 0):

1. memory read to the same area in different thread to the same memory isn't a problem in shared memory systems (write is another matter, the pertinent area is the cache line: 64-256 bytes depending on the system)
2. I don't see any reason for which getting the thread_id should be a synchronized operation. (And you can feed your thread with any id meaningful for you, it can be simpler than getting a meaningful value from an abstract id)

Comment: Say I'm using a structure of arrays, identifying my thread with the variable 'i' defined in the first for loop in main. To identify a thread I will say 'd.Idx = i' (then d.dataPtr=(double_ptr) etc...). In this case I have to use mutex on d.Idx, as the value will change when the next thread is called. My current implementation is an array of structures (which is what the intel paper said is slower) - although all the big elements of the structure point to the same arrays. Its ok to be indexing d[i].stuff (intel says slower) instead of d.stuff[i] (intel says faster).

Comment: in threadFun, d is a local (i.e. stack-based) variable, so the value of d.Idx will be unique for each thread, without using a mutex or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from CUDA probably let's you think to complicated. POSIX threads are much simpler. Basically what you are doing should work, as long as you are only reading in the shared array.

Also, don't forget that CUDA is a dismemberment of C++ and not on C, so some things might look different from that aspect, too. E.g in your code the habit of casting the return from `malloc` is generally frowned upon by real C programmers since it can be the source of subtle errors, there.